# How to update table (from another)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a next problem:
I have two databases: `my` and `not my` (call it `"hammas"`). So in my `hammas` i have 1 table called managers with `email` and `org_unit_id` fields. And in `my` database  i have field called users with `email` and `unit_id`.

Everything's clear? I'm glad. SO , next move.

I have this code:

```
user_emails             = User.find(:all).collect {|r| r.email }

    hammas_managers.each do |email, org_unit_id|
      if !user_emails.include?(email)
        User.create(:email => email, :user_group_id => organisational_unit_id)
      end
    end
```

SO from hammas i get emails and  organisational_unit_id and pasting into my table.

EVERYHING'S WORKS. SUPERB!

But I need: If in `"hammas"` some admin deleted (accidentally or specially) row, so my database still will be keeping  this row (and i must delete it manually). How to I make chek automatically: 
if row is deleted

```
blah blah blah code
User.destroy(:id => ... ) or how?
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean - if a hammas_manager is deleted after a corresponding user was created, how can I delete the user?

Comment: Yes, how i can delete user in MY DB if in hammas_manager this user was deleted too

Comment: Will there be some users who have not originated from hammas_managers?

Comment: noon! all users are from hammas_managers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to users

```
has_one :hammas_manager, :foreign_key => :email, :local_key => :email, dependant => destroy
```

and this to hammas_manager

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :email, :local_key => :email, dependant => destroy
```

Now your application should automatically delete users when it removes the hammas_manager.

In the case you might want to 'clean up' previously orphaned users (ie. no h.m) you could run this in console (having defined the relationship as above):

```
User.all.each{|u| u.destroy if u.hammas_manager.blank?}
```

This is untested so don't run it on production data.

Comment: thank you very much!! i will test this. I cant this wrtie in console => User.all.each{|u| u.destroy if u.hammas_manager.blank?}
...some mistake u.destroy: command not found

Comment: and this one: Unknown key(s): local_key (ArgumentError)